# Rust-analyzer in VSCode to substitute env variables in Cargo path imports

Tags: rust, environment-variables, rust-cargo, rust-analyzer

I have a Cargo workspace and want to use a `WORKSPACE_HOME` environment variable in the import path of local crates.

For instance:  in `$WORKSPACE_HOME/services/api/Cargo.toml`

```
[dependencies]
...
addrbook = { path = "${WORKSPACE_HOME}/pkg/addrbook" }
...
```

I tried adding the environment value to VSCode settings.json (under `rust-analyzer.cargo.extraEnv`) and also tried creating a `.cargo/config.toml` as described [here](https://github.com/rust-lang/cargo/issues/3946#issuecomment-97313299)

```
[env]
WORKSPACE_HOME = { value = "", relative = true }
```

Unfortunately, `cargo metadata` keeps failing saying that it is unable to resolve the path

```
[ERROR rust_analyzer::lsp_utils] rust-analyzer failed to load workspace: Failed to read Cargo metadata from Cargo.toml file /Users/nickdecooman/Documents/Workspace/foobar/Cargo.toml, Some(Version { major: 1, minor: 63, patch: 0 }): Failed to run `"cargo" "metadata" "--format-version" "1" "--manifest-path" "/Users/nickdecooman/Documents/Workspace/foobar/Cargo.toml" "--filter-platform" "x86_64-apple-darwin"`: `cargo metadata` exited with an error: error: failed to load manifest for workspace member `/Users/nickdecooman/Documents/Workspace/foobar/services/api`

Caused by:
  failed to load manifest for dependency `addrbook`

Caused by:
  failed to read `/Users/nickdecooman/Documents/Workspace/foobar/services/api/${WORKSPACE_HOME}/pkg/addrbook/Cargo.toml`

Caused by:
  No such file or directory (os error 2)
```

Comment: Did you try the `virtual manifest` instead: https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/workspaces.html#virtual-workspace